# Make PHP echo <a href= link>

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a value that is retrieved using `$row` hyperlinked to another page, but I can't figure out why it isn't working.

The area specifically is;

```
<td><?php echo $row["ID"]; ?></td>
```

Here is what I am using;

```
<td>
<?php 
 echo <a href='edit-dispatch-report.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "' >" . $row['ID'] . "</a>; 
?>
</td>
```

How come that doesn't work?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to mark the start of the string that has to be echoed with double quote `"` in front of `<a href`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php echo <a
```

You need to pass a string to `echo`. You can't just start writing HTML in the middle of PHP.

That said, it is generally easier to minimise the amount of *HTML in PHP in HTML* that you can.

```
<td>
    <a href='edit-dispatch-report.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>'>
        <?php echo $row['ID']; ?>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: that's perfect, thank you very much for explaining this!!! appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

Please correct the string-

put-

```
<?php
 echo "<a href='edit-dispatch-report.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "'>";
      echo $row['ID'];
 echo "</a>"; 
?>
```

Instead of

```
<?php 
 echo <a href='edit-dispatch-report.php?id=" . $row['ID'] . "' >" . $row['ID'] . "</a>; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     <td><a href="edit-dispatch-report.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>" > <?php echo $row['ID']; ?> </a></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you missed quotation at the start of your echo

2) You do not need to use quotation in the params in the link.
url should be like this:

```
yoursite.com/edit-dispatch-report.php?id=12
```

should not like this:

```
yoursite.com/edit-dispatch-report.php?id='12'
```

Try this:

```
   <?php 
     echo "<a href=\"edit-dispatch-report.php?id={$row['ID']} \" >{$row['ID']}</a>"; 
    ?>
```